# Convert UTF-8 code (e.g., E052E472E04F) to text

Tags: java, android, utf-8

I'm working with some resource I found online which contains UTF-8 codes instead of real texts (since it's Arabic), and I have no idea at all how do I convert this into real texts in Java.

For example:

> breakme~E052E472E04FE46CE04EE051E46F0020E027E04BE43EE052E484E04EE4370020E052E027E47EE04FE478E050E473E412E04EE4630020E052E472E04FE46CE050E051E421E04EE051E0310020E476E050E4730020E050E051E466E04EE434E052E46FE41EE050E4210020E04FE044E47EE04FE443E04EE051E43EE46FE0270020E04FE472E04FE46BE021E41EE04EE42F0020E052E43AE04EE4670020E04FE033E41EE04EE051E478E46FE0270020E41EE04EE47CE04FE051E483E04EE0230020E41EE04EE483breakme

Thank you.

EDIT:

I reverse engineered the source code and here's what I found:

```
public char[] getUnicodeString(String paramString) {
    int j = paramString.length() / 4;
    char[] arrayOfChar = new char[j];
    int i = 0;
    for (; ; ) {
        if (i >= j) {
            return arrayOfChar;
        }
        arrayOfChar[i] = ((char) Integer.parseInt(paramString.substring(i * 4, i * 4 + 4), 16));
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Would that help?

Comment: O.o That's...not what people usually mean when they say "UTF-8 format."  Is that...bytes in hexadecimal that are supposed to be then parsed as UTF-8, maybe?

Comment: lol. Sorry. As I've said, I'm completely ignorant about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is **not UTF-8**. UTF-8 is an encoding where bytes are either single in the range `00-7F`, or multiple with first byte in the range `C0-FF`, followed by 1 to 3 bytes in the range `80-BF`. The shown sequence does not match that pattern, so it cannot be UTF-8.

It appears to be a 2-byte encoding, with some `0020` values, that would appear to be unicode space characters. If you show the 2-byte hex codes separated and break lines after the `0020` space, you get this slightly more human-readable sequence:

```
E052 E472 E04F E46C E04E E051 E46F 0020
E027 E04B E43E E052 E484 E04E E437 0020
E052 E027 E47E E04F E478 E050 E473 E412 E04E E463 0020
E052 E472 E04F E46C E050 E051 E421 E04E E051 E031 0020
E476 E050 E473 0020
E050 E051 E466 E04E E434 E052 E46F E41E E050 E421 0020
E04F E044 E47E E04F E443 E04E E051 E43E E46F E027 0020
E04F E472 E04F E46B E021 E41E E04E E42F 0020
E052 E43A E04E E467 0020
E04F E033 E41E E04E E051 E478 E46F E027 0020
E41E E04E E47C E04F E051 E483 E04E E023 0020
E41E E04E E483
```

So, although `0020` appears to be a space, the rest of the values are `Exxx`, and the entire `E000-F8FF` range is defined in unicode for "Private Use".

So, don't know what it is, but it's not UTF-8 or UTF-16 encodings of unicode.

It could be some old DBCS (double-byte character set) code page, I guess.

Comment: So, what do I do now? Thank you. (please see my edit)

Comment: They seem to be treating it like UTF-16, using the private use area for some non-standard arabic text.

Comment: But what now? hahaha. Could I just use the method above to parse it?

Comment: After stripping off the `breakme` and `~`, sure.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll try it.